# Не работает эффект наведения в css

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, hover

Мучаюсь с эффектом наведения :hover необходимо сделать такой эффект когда при наведении на один элемент меняются свойства другого, вот небольшой пример:

```css
.div_1:hover .div_effect {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_1">
   <div class="wrap">
      <div class="div_1"></div>
      <div class="div_2"></div>
      <div class="div_3"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="block_2">
  <div class="div_effect"></div>
</div>
```

Но такая конструкция не работает, из тестирования понял что эффект отлично применяется на наводимый элемент или на его дочерние элементы, но наведение не работает если элемент к которому оно должно применяться находится за пределами наводимого блока. Подскажите как решить этот вопрос?

P.S. Надеюсь достаточно понятно передал суть проблемы.

Comment: Селектор `.div_1:hover .div_effect` значит элемент с калссом `div_effect` у которого есть родитель с классом `div_1` и при наведении на родителя дать стиль его потомку. а у вас они не вложены друг в друга.

Comment: с вашей html структурой на css нет возможности реализовать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `css` так можно делать, но вложенность элемента ховера должна быть не как в вашей разметке. Вверх в `css` подниматься нельзя.

```css
.div_1, .div_2, .div_3, .div_effect {
  background: green; width: 30px; height: 30px; margin: 5px;
}

.div_1:hover ~ * .div_effect {
  background-color: red;
}

.div_2:hover ~ * .div_effect {
  background-color: orange;
}

.div_3:hover ~ * .div_effect {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_1"></div>
<div class="div_2"></div>
<div class="div_3"></div>

<div class="block_2">
  <div class="div_effect">fx</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, я догадался что в css нельзя вверх подниматься, но ваш метод не работает если не использовать тильду со звездочкой. Объясните пожалуйста почему он так работает а иначе нет, где магия))

Comment: тильда говорит что в той-же вложенности, звездочка что любой элемент. в данном примере звездочка указывает на block_2

Answer (score 3):

Задача решается при помощи JavaScript.

```js
var div1 = document.querySelector('.div_1'),
    effect = document.querySelector('.div_effect');

div1.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  effect.classList.add('hover');
});
div1.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  effect.classList.remove('hover');
});
```

```css
.wrap div,
.div_effect {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.div_effect {
  background-color: blue;
}
.div_effect.hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_1">
   <div class="wrap">
      <div class="div_1">1</div>
      <div class="div_2">2</div>
      <div class="div_3">3</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="block_2">
  <div class="div_effect"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш метод тоже хорош, но как по мне если делать с использованием js то логику наведения лучше максимально приблизить к той что в css. Другими словами не добавляя класс со стилями а использовав методы mouseover/mouseout

Comment: Я его и использую, но для оформления лучше использовать CSS-классы, а не инлайн-стили. По крайней мере в этом случае.